# How to get content from CK Editor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, textarea

I need to get content from CK Editor to put it in JQuery.

```html
 
    <form action="php/showcomments.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" >
    <div class="text-cmt">
     <input id="tittle" name="tittle" type="text" placeholder="Comment Title" id="comm" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-cmt">
     <textarea id="msg"  ></textarea>
 
    </div>
    <div class="text-cmt">
     <input name="send"  type="submit" value="send">
    </div>
    </form>
     <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'msg' );
    </script>
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var g_id = "<?= $id; ?>";
 var u_id = "<?= userid; ?>";
 
  //  var comm = tinyMCE.editor.getContent();
 //tinyMCE.get('editor').getContent()
   $("form").submit(function(){
    var comm =  $("#tittle").val();
     $.ajax({
      url: 'php/showcomments.php', // form action url
      type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
      data: {tittle: $("#tittle").val(),comm: comm, g_id: g_id,  u_id: u_id },
      dataType: 'html',
   success: function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
      },
  });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please provide error message and also live page url so we can check for the error and ckeditor layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get content of ck editor using

**JS for CKEditor 3.6.x**

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('msg');

$('#send').click(function() {
    var value = editor.getData();
    // send your ajax request with value
    // profit!
});
```

**JS for CKEditor 4.0.x**

```
$('#send').click(function() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['DOM-ID-HERE'].getData()
    // send your ajax request with value
    // profit!
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use (value that you are getting from database)|safe.